# Создание сегмента круга

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Как мне сделать с помощью css или svg [сегмент круга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0)? Вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, с помощью псевдоэлемента:

```css
.segment {
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.segment::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="segment"></div>
```

Или фоновым радиальным градиентом:

```css
.segment {
  height: 28px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  background: 0 0 / 200px 200px no-repeat radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, red 199px, transparent 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="segment"></div>
```

Или используйте SVG:

```css
svg {
  height: 28px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

.segment {
  d: path('M 0 28 Q 100 -28 200 28 Z');
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg><path class="segment" /></svg>
```

Comment: Простите за вопрос не по теме, можно ли в css позиционировать элемент не от его края а от центра? То есть left:50%;  и элемент по центру блока

Comment: @Dmitry: элементы нет, позиционирование идёт относительно краёв родителя элемента, но не от центра. Фон можно позиционировать относительно центра (например, `background-position: center -20px center 0px`)

Comment: @UModeL `d: path` в CSS в браузере FF, к сожалению до сих пор не поддерживается, так как нет поддержки в спецификации w3c

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: вот потому и сижу на Хроме ;-) В FF тоже есть фишки, но они какие-то редкоиспользуемые.

Comment: @UModeL может просто перенести path в тело SVG и тогда будет везде работать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: если я перенесу, то от твоего ответа не будет отличаться. Я же, на перспективу, потомкам с допиленным FF )))

Comment: @UModeL ну почему не будет отличаться? У меня арка, у тебя кубическая кривая Безье и выглядит явно ближе к вопросу. Ещё вариант, добавь svg в background в стилях Тоже будет везде работать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: я жеж CSS-ник )) А кубическая первая вспомнилась - там аргументов меньше ))

Answer (score 5):

Наиболее простой способ в SVG получить сегмент с помощью команды path [Arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#arcs)

Всего одна строка path.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="150" viewBox="0 0 400 150"  >  
<path fill="yellowgreen" stroke="none" d="M10 100 A100,30 0 0 1 390 100 h-380" />        
</svg>
```

Размеры и позиционирование сегмента устанавливаются:

- **M mx,my** – координаты начальной точки дуги сегмента
- **A rx,ry** – радиусы дуги сегмента
- **x,y** – координаты конечной точки дуги сегмента

Подробнее [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=900)

Comment: Плюс в карму, по аркам нету пояснений на so

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, кружочек внутри блока-маски:

```css
.mask {
  --R: 100px;
  --h: 40px;
  --border: 2px;

  width: calc(var(--R) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--h) + var(--border) * 2);
  overflow:hidden;
}
.circle {
  width: calc(var(--R) * 2);
  height: calc(var(--R) * 2);
  border: solid var(--border);
  border-radius: 50%; 
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.circle::before {
  content:' ';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: dashed var(--border);
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--h);
}
```

```html
<div class="mask">
  <div class="circle"></div>
<div>
```